# JPackage Unable to Launch JVM - Circular loading of URL stream handler providers detected

Tags: windows, javafx, jpackage

After running jpackage on my JavaFX application using following command:

```cmd
.\jpackage.exe
--input C:\Users\My\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyFX\target\
--dest C:\Users\My\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyFX\
--name "MyFX"
--main-jar C:\Users\My\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyFX\target\MyFX-2.0.jar
--main-class my.myfx.App
--module-path 'C:\Program Files\Java\jmods\\'
--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,java.sql --win-console
```

I'm getting error on launching the program:
`Unable to launch JVM`

Error on console:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Circular loading of URL stream handler providers detected
at java.base/java.net.URL.lookupViaProviders(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.net.URL.getURLStreamHandler(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.tryResolveFile(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.tryResolve(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.parseClassPath(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getClassPath(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$1.next(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$1.hasMoreElements(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader$1.hasNext(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader$1.hasMoreElements(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.CompoundEnumeration.next(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.net.URL$1.getNext(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.net.URL$1.hasNext(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.net.URL$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.net.URL$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.net.URL.lookupViaProviders(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.net.URL.getURLStreamHandler(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.tryResolveFile(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.tryResolve(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.parseClassPath(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getClassPath(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Failed to launch JVM

Are there any more libraries to add? any more JMods? What does "Circular loading of URL streams" have to do with this?

EDIT: **MyFX.App**

```java
package my.myfx;
    public static javafx.scene.image.Image loadingImg,tickImg,appIconImg;
    public static javafx.scene.image.ImageView loading,tick,appIcon;
    private static javafx.scene.Scene scene;
    @Override
    public void start(javafx.stage.Stage stage) throws java.io.IOException {
        try{
            appIcon=new ImageView();
            appIconImg=new Image(getClass().getResource("icons/icon.png").toURI().toString());
            appIcon.setImage(appIconImg);
            loading=new ImageView();
            loadingImg=new Image(getClass().getResource("icons/loading.gif").toURI().toString());
            loading.setImage(loadingImg);
            javafx.concurrent.Task<Exception>work=new javafx.concurrent.Task<>(){
                @Override
                protected Exception call(){
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(500);  //Simulate IO operation
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        return ex;
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
            new Thread(work).start();
            scene = new javafx.scene.Scene(new javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/main.fxml")).load(), 640, 480);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setMaximized(true);
            stage.setTitle("MyFX");
            stage.getIcons().add(appIconImg);
            stage.show();
            work.setOnSucceeded(e->{
                try{
                    if(work.get()==null){
                        System.out.println("Folders initialized");
                        tick=new ImageView();
                        tickImg=new Image(getClass().getResource("icons/tick.png").toURI().toString(),true);
                        tick.setImage(tickImg);
                    }else{
                       System.out.println(work.get());
                    }
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            });
            stage.setOnCloseRequest((javafx.stage.WindowEvent t) -> {
                Platform.exit();
                System.exit(0);
            });
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    static void setRoot(){
        try{
            scene.setRoot(new javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("fxml/main.fxml")).load());
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

This also contains some functions but they're mostly getters for other classes

Comment: If you look at the stack trace, you can see `java.net.URL.getURLStreamHandler` called twice.  I guess that is the circle.  What caused it I don't know.  It appears to be some issue that occurs during service lookup.  A weird thing is that it is a "JNI error", so occurs in native code.

Comment: Can you show your main class?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Slaw do you mean the `App` class?

Comment: @jewelsea is that error occurring because of some code in my program? I think this error is prior to my code execution.

Comment: Yes, I mean the `my.myfx.App` class. Though I'm only asking to see it in the unlikely event the problem could be coming from initializing that class. I say unlikely because none of the frames in the stack trace are from your code. In general, if you could provide a [mre], that would be even better.

Comment: Hmm. Nothing extra seems to be done when the class is loaded, so that can't be the problem. I notice you reference a `target` directory in the `jpackage` command. Is this a Maven project? Because doing `--input ...\target` will include _everything_ inside that directory. I wonder if that means something is being included that's causing your problem. What happens if you `--input` only the files you need (e.g., your project's JAR and any dependency JARs); you may need to create a new directory containing only the JAR files for this, not sure.

Comment: *"is that error occurring because of some code in my program?"* -> no, there is nothing in your code to cause this error.  Perhaps it is caused by an environment or packaging error (as stated earlier, I don't know the cause).

Comment: Unrelated, minor note but don't call `System.exit()`.  The [`Application` javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) makes a recommendation on this when discussing the application lifecycle.  Instead, either mark your usef thread as [daemon threads](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)), or send them a signal to gracefully shut themselves down from the `Application` [`stop`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#stop()) method.

Comment: @Slaw contents of `target`: `classes, generated-sources, generated-test-sources, lib, maven-archiver, maven-status, test-classes`. I copied the `MyFX-2.0.jar` to `lib` folder

Comment: The `lib` folder contains all the dependencies for the project: `commons-codec-1.15.jar,commons-collections4-4.4.jar,commons-compress-1.21.jar,commons-io-2.11.0.jar,commons-math3-3.6.1.jar,curvesapi-1.07.jar,jarchivelib-1.2.0.jar,javafx-base-19-win.jar,avafx-base-19.jar,javafx-controls-19-win.jar,javafx-controls-19.jar,javafx-fxml-19-win.jar
javafx-fxml-19.jar,javafx-graphics-19-win.jar,javafx-graphics-19.jar,log4j-api-2.19.0.jar,log4j-core-2.19.0.jar,poi-5.2.3.jar,poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar,poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.3.jar,MyFX-2.0.jar,SparseBitSet-1.2.jar,sqlite-jdbc-3.39.3.0.jar,xmlbeans-5.1.1.jar`